# jQuery generate and select id

Tags: jquery, html

I want to generate some code on client side using jquery by setting its html contents using `.html()` to a specific id.  Here's the example to show what I am doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/dEJZF/4/

For my class `chat-links`, it will alert hi if I coded it as such under HTML, but it would not 
work if I generate it by setting the same line of code under another the html content id of 
`chat-test`.  My question is, how can I generate that line of code, set it under the id `chat-test` in this case, and would still be able to identify it with the class name `chat-links` instead of `chat-test` ?  Or is there a way so that I can change the id of `chat-test` into `chat-links`?

So basically, I want it to be able to alert hi when I click def.

Thanks.

Comment: Well first off, your demo is flawed since you duplicate IDs and they must be unique.

Comment: k, I changed it into a class instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're adding elements to the DOM dynamically, you need to use `.on()` instead of `.click()` to delegate the event handling.

```
$(document).on('click', '.chat-links a', function () {
    alert("hi");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dEJZF/5/)**